# ES6 Node.js import then rewrite the file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Is it a possible to import a JSON file in node.js update some properties in the JSON then write the new data back into place?

Would it be better to use `fs` to read the file then write the file again?

I am trying to whip up a stupid simple prototype DB using JSON.

```
export const Users = [
  {
    username: 'Mike'
  }
]

export const Websites = [
  {
    owner: 'Mike',
    website: 'michael-aubry',
    build: {
        header: {
            component: 'header',
            navigation: 'standard'
        },
        main: {
            works: true,
            card: 1
        }
    }
  }
]

export const Works = [
  {
    owner: 'Mike',
    items: [
      {title: 'Dribbble Thanks', image_src: './dribbble_thanks.png'},
      {title: 'My WIP', image_src: 'bloomthat.png'},
      {title: 'Michael Angelo', image_src: 'https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/371472/screenshots/2847709/studio-minted-case-studies-promo.jpg'},
      {title: 'Beautiful Art', image_src: 'https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/4094/screenshots/2846992/drib106.jpg'}
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about this in a slightly different way.

We can't use `import` to write back to a JSON file, and if the JSON file shouldn't *permanently* change, we don't necessarily want to write back to it.

What if you had a module that read the JSON file, and then other files would import *this* module to use and manipulate that data?

```
// data.json
{
  "users": ...,
  "websites": ...,
  "works": ...
}
```

---

```
// data.js
import data from './data.json'
export default data
```

And now you can import from `data.js` and modify those values.

Comment: Good luck @MichaelJosephAubry!